# What is C2Compiler::compile_method compiling?

Tags: java, jvm, java-11

I collected the Flamegraph of the execution of a Unit Test I've written in Java and 90% of the time is being spent in compiling the code `C2Compiler::compile_method`.

Is there a way to figure out what exactly is compiling? Which Methods?

Comment: If CPU profiler shows the most time is spent in JIT compilation, this does not yet mean a performance problem. This is absolutely normal, especially at an early stage after the program starts. JIT compiler works in a background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can for instance use the `-Xlog:jit+compilation=debug:file=comp_log_%p.txt` VM flag to log compilations. This will write the log to the `comp_log_[pid].txt` file.

The output looks something like this:

```
[0.032s][debug][jit,compilation]    1       3       java.lang.String::charAt (25 bytes)
[0.032s][debug][jit,compilation]    2       3       java.lang.StringLatin1::charAt (15 bytes)
[0.033s][debug][jit,compilation]    7       3       java.lang.StringLatin1::hashCode (42 bytes)
[0.033s][debug][jit,compilation]    5       3       java.lang.Object::<init> (1 bytes)
[0.033s][debug][jit,compilation]   10       3       java.util.ImmutableCollections$SetN::probe (56 bytes)
[0.033s][debug][jit,compilation]    6       3       java.lang.String::hashCode (60 bytes)
[0.033s][debug][jit,compilation]   12       3       java.lang.StringLatin1::equals (36 bytes)
[0.034s][debug][jit,compilation]    9       3       java.lang.Math::floorMod (20 bytes)
```

The first number is the compilation id, the second number is the compilation level. Any compilation with a level of `4` is a C2 compilation, so that's the ones you want to look for.

Other symbols in this log mean the following:

- `%` = an OSR (on stack replacement) compilation
- `s` = a synchronized method
- `!` = compiled code has an exception handler
- `b` = compilation task is blocking (for instance as a result of using `-Xbatch`)
- `n` = a `native` method

Comment: @emitrax You can use `-Xlog:help` for the doc, or look here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/java.html#enable-logging-with-the-jvm-unified-logging-framework There's no documentation on the format of this specific log message AFAIA. I got the information in the answer by looking at the source code (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0d93ab9dff04409469faa26d5cdb29c4d6488537/src/hotspot/share/compiler/compileTask.cpp#L252)